# Deserializing a JSON value from an API - curly vs. square brackets

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I am working to integrate some weather info from an API where I get a return value like this ...

```
{"coord":{"lon":-85.6,"lat":43.05},"weather":[{"id":803,"main":"Clouds","description":"broken clouds","icon":"04d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":277.33,"pressure":1010,"humidity":65,"temp_min":276.15,"temp_max":279.15},"visibility":16093,"wind":{"speed":5.7,"deg":100,"gust":8.2},"clouds":{"all":75},"dt":1524076680,"sys":{"type":1,"id":1410,"message":0.0043,"country":"US","sunrise":1524048860,"sunset":1524097768},"id":420018526,"name":"Grand Rapids","cod":200}
```

I have created a `built_value` and `built_collection` object to deserialize into.  If I build the object "by hand" and serialize it, and JSON encode it ...

```
var w = new Welcome((b) => b
 ..id = 420018526
 ..name = "Grand Rapids"
 ..weather.add(new Weather((w)=>w
    ..id = 803
    ..main = "Clouds"
    ..description = "broken clouds"
    ..icon = "04d"
  ))
 ..cod = 200
 ..coord.lat = 43.05
 ..coord.lon= -85.6
 ..base = 'stations'
 ..main.temp = 277.33
 ..main.pressure = 1010
 ..main.humidity = 65
 ..main.temp_min = 276.15
 ..main.temp_max = 279.15
 ..visibility = 16093
 ..wind.speed = 5.7
 ..wind.deg = 100
 ..wind.gust = 8.2
 ..clouds.all = 75
..dt = 1524076680
..sys.type = 1
..sys.id = 1410
..sys.message = 0.0043
..sys.country = "US"
..sys.sunrise = 1524048860
..sys.sunset = 1524097768
 );

var ws = serializers.serialize(w);
var wsj = JSON.encode(ws);
```

I get something like this ...

```
["Welcome","coord",["lon",-85.6,"lat",43.05],"weather",[["id",803,"main","Clouds","description","broken clouds","icon","04d"]],"base","stations","main",["temp",277.33,"pressure",1010,"humidity",65,"temp_min",276.15,"temp_max",279.15],"visibility",16093,"wind",["speed",5.7,"deg",100,"gust",8.2],"clouds",["all",75],"dt",1524076680,"sys",["type",1,"id",1410,"message",0.0043,"country","US","sunrise",1524048860,"sunset",1524097768],"id",420018526,"name","Grand Rapids","cod",200]
```

... which looks amazingly similar, but you'll notice that the `dart:convert` JSON libraries seem to prefer square brackets [ over curly ones {

When I try to deserialze the curly brackets `wsjdA = JSON.decode(wJson);` I get an error

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Welcome' of 'wsjdA' where
  _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
  String is from dart:core
  Welcome is from package:ex_models/src/weather.dart
```

But if I do this goofy thing (to parse out the square brackets for curly and add the first string "Welcome" ...

```
var wJsonB= '["Welcome",' + wJson
  .replaceAll('{', '[')
  .replaceAll('}', ']')
  .replaceAll(':', ',')
  .substring(1);
```

... it works fine

Am I missing something - is there an easier way to do the JSON/Object deserialization in `dart`. I'd really like to be able to parse a valid JSON API response into a dart object, in a standard way, without the manual parsing.

I think this may have worked if it weren't for the list of Weather objects within the Root/Welcome object.  Because this object contains a list of objects, this is confusing things a bit?  This is a `BuiltList` in my object.

I am already using a `built_value` object with `built_collections` and using the `dart:convert` libraries.  Wondering if there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` is for lists/arrays, `{}` is for maps. With `built_value` you can use properties of type `BuiltList` and `BuiltMap`.

`JSON.decode(wJson);` doesn't return instances of classes, it just makes lists, maps, and separate primitive values out of a JSON string.

`built_value` has it's own serialization from what `JSON.decode(...)` returns to concrete instances of classes.

`built_value` by default has a reduced JSON format that won't be compatible with your JSON. For that you need to register the [StandardJsonPlugin](https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/blob/master/built_value/lib/standard_json_plugin.dart) (see also https://github.com/google/built_value.dart/issues/171)

For details about serialization with `built_value` see https://medium.com/dartlang/darts-built-value-for-serialization-f5db9d0f4159.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the StandardJsonPlugin tip ... much closer

final standardSerializers = (serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(new StandardJsonPlugin())).build();

var wJson2 = '{"\$":"Welcome",' + responseText.substring(1);

var wsjdA = JSON.decode(wJson2);
Welcome wsdcA = standardSerializers.deserialize(wsjdA);

My only piece missing here is it seems to want/require the first element {"$","Welcome",

Where "Welcome" is the classname - all the rest works as advertised - working on this.

Comment: final value = standardSerializers.deserializeWith(Welcome.serializer, JSON.decode(responseText));

using "deserializeWith" added the context so the "discriminator" ($/Welcome) was not necessary - marking this as my answer - thanks!

Also, added the "standardSerializers" to my existing serializers.dart so both the "dart/stock" and "standardized" serializers are in the class together and will be useful elsewhere.